# Libgdx input after creating an orthographic view off

Tags: camera, libgdx, coordinates, viewport, aspect-ratio

The input coordinates are off after I have created an OrthographicCamera using a viewport width and height of 480px*320p. How would I go about fixing this? Another question to with the viewport aspect ratio, how would I go about having a few fixed sizes and adjusting to the phones aspect ratio?

Comment: `stage.getViewport().update(width, height, true)` (or maybe false) in your `resize` method. that should fix the problem.

Comment: I am not using stage for the things people will touch on the screen, would you know how I would go about that? @noone

Comment: On your input use the `camera.unproject(inputx,inputy,inputz)` (with inputz if 2d substitute with 0) method, this should set the input coords to what you are using in the camera.

Comment: @DuhProgrammer13 When I do this the input is a little off?

Comment: okay, then you still need to do `viewport.update(Gdx.graphics.getWidth,... Height)`. And use `viewport.unproject()` instead of `camera.unproject`

Comment: also have a look at this: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports... maybe you are searching for `ExtendViewport`, but unfortunately, that's the only one I didn't code myself and haven't used it so far.

Comment: @noone thank you for your help I am extremely grateful how would I go about it using Libgdx 0.9.9?

Comment: Well, `Viewport` doesn't do much more than setting `camera.viewportWidth/Height`. How to calculate those for different aspect ratios, you can maybe copypaste that part from the `Viewport` source. For input processing you would then need to use `Camera.unproject(coords, viewportX, ViewportY, viewportWidht, viewportHeight)`.

Comment: I use the tutorial here: http://www.acamara.es/blog/2012/02/keep-screen-aspect-ratio-with-different-resolutions-using-libgdx/

Comment: Like @noone said you then need to use `camera.unproject(Vector3 touchpos)`, which calculates the worlcoordinates out of your screen coordinates.

Comment: @Springbua When I do this the touch coordinates are off I use an InputProcessor as well that handles input and then calls the appropriate method in the screen classes

Comment: @noone Would you know why its causing this?

Comment: Do you use this? `Camera.unproject(coords, viewportX, ViewportY, viewportWidht, viewportHeight)`

Comment: yes @noone would you know whats causing it?

Comment: No, it worked like that for me in version 0.9.9...

Comment: Ill have a look over my code. @noone would you have any idea on how to adjust the aspect ratio according to the phone?